# Reduce takes forever to solve an equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm facing a problem in solving an equation with `Reduce`. My goal is to find the turning point of a function and to do this I want to find the points at which its second derivative cancels. The second derivative is the complex function below:

```
derivativeTrack2[z_, σ_, δ_, τ_, L_] = -(1/(2 σ^4)) I (E^(-(((L - 2 z + 2 τ) (L - 2 z - 4 I δ σ^2 +  2 τ))/(  8 σ^2))) (L -   2 (z + σ + I δ σ^2 - τ)) (L +   2 (-z + σ - I δ σ^2 + τ)) +  E^(-(((L - 2 z + 2 τ) (L - 2 z + 4 I δ σ^2 +   2 τ))/( 8 σ^2))) (L -  2 (z + σ - I δ σ^2 - τ)) (L +   2 (-z + σ + I δ σ^2 + τ)) +   E^(-(((L - 2 (z + τ)) (L -  2 (z - 2 I δ σ^2 + τ)))/(  8 σ^2))) (L -    2 (z + σ - I δ σ^2 + τ)) (L -  2 (z + σ (-1 - I δ σ) + τ)) +  E^(((L - 2 (z + τ)) (-L +   2 (z + 2 I δ σ^2 + τ)))/( 8 σ^2)) (L -   2 (z + σ + I δ σ^2 + τ)) (L -  2 (z + σ (-1 + I δ σ) + τ)))
```

where Sigma, Delta, Tau and L are the parameters of my function.
If I try to solve directly this equation with `Reduce`, it gives me

*Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.*

What I did the is to plot the absolute value, the real and the immaginary part of the above function like this `Plot[Abs[derivativeTrack2[z, 1, 10, 1, 3]], {z, 0, 3}]` to check whether the function would be zero in any point, and indeed it does. Its real part is zero in the interval considered while its imaginary part oscillates non-periodically. The equation I'm trying to solve has solutions then.

To overcome the `Reduce` error shown above, I performed `ComplexExpand` and `FullySimplify` on my function, which gave me the below output function

```
    FullSimplify[
        ComplexExpand[derivativeTrack2[z, σ, δ, τ, L]]
       , Assumptions -> {σ > 0, L > 0}
    ]
    (* (1/(σ^4))I E^(-(((L - 2 z)^2 + 4 τ^2)/( 4 σ^2))) (E^((L - 2 (z + τ))^2/( 8 σ^2)) (4 (σ^2 + δ^2 σ^4) - (L - 2 z + 2 τ)^2) Cos[1/2 δ (L - 2 z + 2 τ)] +  E^((L - 2 z + 2 τ)^2/( 8 σ^2)) (4 (σ^2 + δ^2 σ^4) - (L -  2 (z + τ))^2) Cos[1/2 δ (L - 2 (z + τ))] -   4 δ σ^2 (E^((L - 2 (z + τ))^2/( 8 σ^2)) (L - 2 z + 2 τ) Sin[ 1/2 δ (L - 2 z + 2 τ)] +  E^((L - 2 z + 2 τ)^2/( 8 σ^2)) (L - 2 (z + τ)) Sin[ 1/2 δ (L - 2 (z + τ))])) *)
```

If now I use `Reduce[Im@Out[18]==0&&0<z<=3,z]` it runs but it never actually solve the equation. It seems it is stuck in a infinite loop and it never gives me the solution. I tried with `Solve` as well, facing still the same problem.

Any advice on how to get the solution of the equation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try the `Reals` options to Reduce, sometimes that helps.

Comment: @Nasser unfortunately not in this case

Comment: No chance. Denoting `out= FullSimplify[
        ComplexExpand[derivativeTrack2[z, σ, δ, τ, L]]
       , Assumptions -> {σ > 0, L > 0}`, we see that the result of  `ComplexExpand[Im@out] == 0` is a  complicated transcendental equation in `z`.

Comment: Here are two terms in the LHS `...(4 (E^((L - 2 (z + \[Tau]))^2/\[Sigma]^2))^(1/8)
   z^2 Cos[
   1/2 \[Delta] (L - 2 z + 2 \[Tau])])/((E^((L - 2 z)^2/\[Sigma]^2 + (
    4 \[Tau]^2)/\[Sigma]^2))^(1/4) \[Sigma]^4) + (
 4 (E^((L - 2 (z + \[Tau]))^2/\[Sigma]^2))^(1/8)
   Cos[1/2 \[Delta] (L - 2 z + 2 \[Tau])])/((E^((L - 
      2 z)^2/\[Sigma]^2 + (4 \[Tau]^2)/\[Sigma]^2))^(1/4) \[Sigma]^2)...`

Comment: $$ \frac{4 z^2 \sqrt[8]{e^{\frac{(L-2 (\tau +z))^2}{\sigma ^2}}} \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \delta  (L+2 \tau -2 z)\right)}{\sigma ^4 \sqrt[4]{e^{\frac{(L-2 z)^2}{\sigma ^2}+\frac{4 \tau ^2}{\sigma ^2}}}}+\frac{4 \sqrt[8]{e^{\frac{(L-2 (\tau +z))^2}{\sigma ^2}}} \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \delta  (L+2 \tau -2 z)\right)}{\sigma ^2 \sqrt[4]{e^{\frac{(L-2 z)^2}{\sigma ^2}+\frac{4 \tau ^2}{\sigma ^2}}}}$$

Comment: @user64494 Ok, I see. But I thought that by restricting the domain, the equation could be solved. Also because there are actually points at which the equation cancels. I would only need to find one point where it cancels.